# Jquery game man vs computer needs a reset button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here I got a fully working game but is missing the following:

- simulate a game (Computer vs Computer)
- restart the game = NOT DONE

Do I need to simulate the click ... maybe on a timer  for computer vs computer?
Do I need to be able to reset the game to the state it is at when the page loads after each game is complete
any help would be much appreciated:-)

https://jsfiddle.net/hdsab90j/1/

```js
var module = {
    init: function () {
        this.gameSetup();

    },

    gameSetup: function () {

        var pedra = "img/rock.png";
        var papel = "img/paper.png";
        var tesoura = "img/scissors.png";

        var userChoice;
        var i = 3;
        var computerChoice;

        $(".button").on("click", startup);

        function startup(e) {
            $(".button").off("click");

            userChoice = e.target.id;

            console.info(userChoice);

            compChoice();

            $(".score").hide();
            $('.lose').removeClass('lose');


            countDown();

        };

        function compChoice() {
            computerChoice = Math.random();
            if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
                computerChoice = "rock";
            } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
                computerChoice = "paper";
            } else {
                computerChoice = "scissors";
            }
        };

        function countDown() {
            count();
        };

        function count() {
            $(".result").text(i);
            if (i === 0) {
                results();
            } else {
                i--;
                setTimeout(count, 400);
            }
        };

        function comparar(choice1, choice2) {
            if (choice1 == choice2) {
                $(".result").text("Tie!");
            } else if (
            (choice1 == "rock" && choice2 == "scissors") || (choice1 == "scissors" && choice2 == "paper") || (choice1 == "paper" && choice2 == "rock")) {
                $(".result").text("You win!");
            } else {
                $(".result").text("You lose!").addClass('lose');
            }

        };

        function results() {
            $(".fist").hide();
            $(".score.left." + userChoice).show();
            $(".score.right." + computerChoice).show();

            comparar(userChoice, computerChoice);

            $(".button").on("click", startup);
        };

    }

};



$(document).ready(function () {
    module.init();
});
```

```css
body, header, section, h1, img, button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    background: #191919;
    font: 700 2em/1em'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
header h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px
}
header h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px
}
section {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
section .content {
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    display: table;
}
section .content > div {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
section .content > div img {
    max-width: 60%;
    height: auto;
}
section .controlls {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}
section .controlls h1 {
    color: black;
    margin-bottom:150px;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
section .controlls h1.lose {
    color:red;
}
.buttons {
    margin: auto;
    widows: 100%;
    display: table;
    padding-top:130px;
}
button {
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
    position: relative;
    background-size: 100%;
    /*text-indent: -999em;*/
    display: table-cell;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #222;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    transform: translatez(0);
    margin-left: 15px;
}
button:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
 
}
button:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
}
button.rock:after {
    background: url(../images/rock.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
button.paper:after {
    background: url(../images/paper.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
button.scissor:after {
    background: url(../images/scissor.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
button:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -mz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
button:first-child {
    margin-left:0:
}
#rock_right, #paper_right, #scissors_right, #rock_left, #paper_left, #scissors_left {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="content">
        <div>
             <h2 class="">MAN</h2>

            <img src="images/rock.png" class="score left rock" id="rock_left" alt="rock" />
            <img src="images/paper.png" class="score left paper" id="paper_left" alt="paper" />
            <img src="images/scissor.png" class="score left scissors" id="scissors_left" alt="scissor" />
        </div>
        <div>
             <h2 class="">Robot</h2>

            <img src="images/rock.png" class="score right rock" id="rock_right" alt="rock" />
            <img src="images/paper.png" class="score right paper" id="paper_right" alt="paper" />
            <img src="images/scissor.png" class="score right scissors" id="scissors_right" alt="scissor" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controlls">
         <h1 class="result"></h1>

        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button clickable rock" id="rock">Rock</button>
            <button class="button clickable paper" id="paper">Paper</button>
            <button class="button clickable scissor" id="scissors">Scissor</button>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <input type="text" value="reset" id="reset"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Cool jsfiddle :) please include the correct link

Comment: bloody pc!!!! sorry https://jsfiddle.net/hdsab90j/1/

Comment: @devqon did you have a chance to see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your existing computer choice to return the value rather than update global/module level variable:

```
    function compChoice() {
        computerChoice = Math.random();
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) return "rock";
        if (computerChoice <= 0.67) return "paper";
        return "scissors";
    };
```

then you could re-call this to get the computer-vs-computer result and auto-click the corresponding button.

```
function computerVcomputer() {
    var comp1 = compChoice();
    $("#" + comp1").click();
}
```

there's some other issues with the timer, but the above is for the computer-vs-computer.

Comment: thanks for this , could u make this working on a fiddle please?

Comment: for the reset ?function reset (){
          $(".reset").on("click", function(){
            location.reload();
          });
          
        };
        reset();

Answer (score 0):

Did I get it right? You ask how to reset the Timer? 
Try setting your counter (variable called i in your code) to it's initial value (3 in your case) within your startup function. This will reset the timer.
I did not see any code that handles a computer vs computer game...

Comment: Not sure this answers the question. If you're unsure what the OP wants, add a comment to clarify the question

Comment: I want to reset the game, and also play computer vs computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. to fix the timer issue

`if (i === 0) {
 results();
 i=3;
 }`

2. to restart the game you can simply reload the page `location.reload();`
3. to do the computer vs computer you can add another button and put an event on it

`var e={}; e.target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
$(".button2").on("click", startup(e));`

Comment: thanks, could you double check my fiddle please? https://jsfiddle.net/hdsab90j/4/

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this..

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xwt9Lf0c/4/

```
var module = {
init: function () {
    this.gameSetup();

},

gameSetup: function () {

    var pedra = "img/rock.png";
    var papel = "img/paper.png";
    var tesoura = "img/scissors.png";

    var userChoice;
    var i = 3;
    var computerChoice;

    $("#game").off("click").on("click", reset);
    $(".button").off("click").on("click", startup);
       function demo(e) {                                      
$("#paper").addClass("hoverSimulate").trigger("click");
    }


      function start(e) {                                   
   $(".result").text("");i=3;$(".score").hide();
 }
       function reset(e) {
            if($(e.target).hasClass("start")){
            $("#reset").toggleClass("demo start").val("Start");
                  start();

            }
            else
            {
                demo();
            }

    }
    function startup(e) {
        $(".button").off("click");

        userChoice = e.target.id;

        console.info(userChoice);

        compChoice();

        $(".score").hide();
        $('.lose').removeClass('lose');


        countDown();

    };

    function compChoice() {
        computerChoice = Math.random();
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
            computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        }
    };

    function countDown() {
        count();
    };

    function count() {
        $(".result").text(i);
        if (i === 0) {
            results();
        } else {
            i--;
            setTimeout(count, 400);
        }
    };

    function comparar(choice1, choice2) {
        if (choice1 == choice2) {
            $(".result").text("Tie!");
        } else if (
        (choice1 == "rock" && choice2 == "scissors") || (choice1 == "scissors" && choice2 == "paper") || (choice1 == "paper" && choice2 == "rock")) {
            $(".result").text("You win!");
        } else {
            $(".result").text("You lose!").addClass('lose');
        }
        $("#game").toggleClass("demo start").val("Start");
    };

    function results() {
        $(".fist").hide();
        $(".score.left." + userChoice).show();
        $(".score.right." + computerChoice).show();

        comparar(userChoice, computerChoice);

        $(".button").on("click", startup);
    };

}

};


$(document).ready(function () {
    module.init();
});
```

Comment: thanks but is not fully working. I have to simulate the game, by clicking simulate. And being able to reset it.